# handle spark state istimingout

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, state, spark-streaming

I'm using the new `mapWithState` function in spark streaming (1.6) with a timing out state. I want to use the timing out state and add it to another rdd in order to use it for calculations further down the road:

```
val aggedlogs = sc.emptyRDD[MyLog];
val mappingFunc = (key: String, newlog: Option[MyLog], state: State[MyLog]) => {
val _newLog  =  newlog.getOrElse(null)
    if ((state.exists())&&(_newLog!=null))
    {
        val stateLog = state.get()
        val combinedLog = LogUtil.CombineLogs(_newLog, stateLog);
        state.update(combinedLog)                        
    }
    else if (_newLog !=null) {
        state.update(_newLog);
    }

    if (state.isTimingOut())
    {
        val stateLog = state.get();
        aggedlogs.union(sc.parallelize(List(stateLog), 1))
    }
    val  stateLog = state.get();
    (key,stateLog);            
}

val stateDstream = reducedlogs.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunc).timeout(Seconds(10)))
```

but when I try to add it to an rdd in the StateSpec function, I get an error that the function is not serializable. Any thoughts on how I can get pass this?

EDIT: 
After drilling deeper i found that my approach was wrong. before trying this solution i tried to get the timing out logs from the statesnapeshot(), but they were not there anymore, changing the mapping function to :

```
def  mappingFunc(key: String, newlog: Option[MyLog], state: State[KomoonaLog]) :  Option[(String, MyLog)] = {      
             val  _newLog  =  newlog.getOrElse(null)
                     if ((state.exists())&&(_newLog!=null))
                     {
                         val stateLog = state.get()
                                 val combinedLog = LogUtil.CombineLogs(_newLog, stateLog);
                         state.update(combinedLog)                           
                 Some(key,combinedLog);
                     }
                     else if (_newLog !=null) {
                         state.update(_newLog);
                          Some(key,_newLog);
                     }

             if (state.isTimingOut())
             {
                 val stateLog = state.get();
                  stateLog.timinigOut = true;   
                 System.out.println("timinigOut  : " +key );                     
                 Some(key, stateLog);                    
             } 
               val  stateLog = state.get();
              Some(key,stateLog);            

         }
```

i managed to filter the mapedwithstatedstream for the logs that are timing out in each batch:

```
val stateDstream = reducedlogs.mapWithState(
    StateSpec.function(mappingFunc _).timeout(Seconds(60)))    

  val tiningoutlogs=   stateDstream.filter (filtertimingout)
```